# How might one go about making a usurped or deposed regional Lord as a PC?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

I've been wanting to figure out a new and interesting character to make for the next game my group runs, and I wanted a character with very strict 'win conditions' so he doesn't end up adventuring forever.

I figured a deposed small region ruler might serve the purpose: the reason he adventures is to get strong enough to reclaim his land, rather than for gold, glory, or god. Assuming he can achieve that, his story is done.

But I can't find any information on making a compelling/interesting character with that sort of basis. How to build them and such.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Unfortunately, this sort of idea-generation question seems entirely opinion-based; there's no way to choose a "best" answer to a question like this, as any answer could be equally valid. Such questions are better suited to a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go).